Android Studio LadyBug Project Corruption (Gradle issue?)
Since upgrading to Android Studio LadyBug I am encountering the fatal error "Could not move temporary workspace". Once the error occurs the project is irretrievably corrupted.
Question
Has anyone found a way to recover from this error?
Background
The Sync Tab shows
failed
Download info
Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\<NAME>\.gradle\caches\8.9\transforms\c17ff7a71a7540ad7b81fa15a8578109-85b2a633-b495-4674-a04c-c5ddb6345645) to immutable location (C:\Users\<NAME>\.gradle\caches\8.9\transforms\c17ff7a71a7540ad7b81fa15a8578109)

The error appears to relate to the Gradle system (hence why I added 'Gradle issue' to the title)
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 1 s 367 ms

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'ShowTime'.
> A build operation failed.
      Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\<NAME>\.gradle\caches\8.9\transforms\c17ff7a71a7540ad7b81fa15a8578109-85b2a633-b495-4674-a04c-c5ddb6345645) to immutable location (C:\Users\<NAME>\.gradle\caches\8.9\transforms\c17ff7a71a7540ad7b81fa15a8578109)

Once I encounter this error the project is irretrievably broken.
In earlier versions of Android Studio I solved infrequent project corruptions by simply deleting the corrupted project and restoring a backup.
When I try restoring a project backup I am shown exactly the same error, right down to exactly the same filenames
I have tried all the earlier solutions posted (here and here) but deleting caches, specific files, using import instead of open, etc. have not worked for the above error
Project corruption used to occur intermittently in earlier versions of Android Studio. Since "upgrading" to Android Studio LadyBug I have irretrievably lost five (5) different projects, all with the same "Could not move temporary workspace" error (but different filenames)
I am reaching out because having the error occur on an almost daily basis suggests others are likely to be encountering similar errors
Edit
I have now tried uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio (manually deleting the .gradle directory). When I opened a formally good project, the above error appeared (so I now have 6 irretrievably corrupted apps in 6 days).

What operating system are you using? Cached files that you might need to delete are in different places on different operating systems.

@RichardParkins Windows 11 Pro. I have targeted the .gradle directory and \AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2024.2

Update
Bitdefender have released an update which appears to have fixed the above problem
Original Details
This issue affects PC's using Bitdefender Advanced Threat Defense and Gradle version greater than 8.5
The workaround involves

Open Bitdefender going to Advanced Threat Defense and selecting Open.
Click on the Settings tab and then on Manage Exceptions
Type in c:\program files\android\android studio\jbr\bin\java.exe and
check the switch to exclude it
Save

No other changes were necessary
This is all discussed on the Gradle issue tracker here.
One user suggests creating a separate version of Java, but since Android Studio ships with its own implementation it seems to be overkill (please correct me if that is incorrect)
